# Detecting swipe events in Appgyver app

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, steroids

Are there any directives to detect swipe events? If not, how can I use something like angular-touch?

An example case is i want to hide a modal on swipe up.

Answer (score 0):

I have just used angular-touch on an app and it seems to work well.

Simply download angular-touch.js from the web or use NPM install angular-touch and it will download a node module. I did this and then copied angular-touch.js into my scripts folder with my app.js file. I then added a script link to the file and then declared the module in my app includes [ngTouch].

To use, all you have to do in the container div in the page is add ng-swipe-left="function()" or ng-swipe-right="function". Remember, the function must be written in your controller for the action to actually happen.

e.g.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Having just re-read your problem, I am not sure if this will work for your. I know it does swipe left and write and improves touch but not sure about up and down. Haven't looked into this. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch is a good place to start.